# cls is used in a python function which is not a class

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to understand this function that visualize gradient of a deep learning model

```
def grad_cam(input_model, image, cls, layer_name, H=320, W=320):
    """GradCAM method for visualizing input saliency."""
    y_c = input_model.output[0, cls]
    conv_output = input_model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    grads = K.gradients(y_c, conv_output)[0]
```

As far as i know, cls is use for class method but this function is not defined in any class.  May I know what does it mean and how does it work in the line

```
y_c = input_model.output[0, cls]
```

Comment: ``cls``, ``self`` and others are just conventions, you may name your variables however you want in python, as long as they are valid variable names.

Comment: `cls` is not a function, it's a parameter for the grad_cam function. In the future, it would help if you included a reference for where you found this code. That said, I'm guessing it's from [this gradcam implementation](https://github.com/eclique/keras-gradcam/blob/master/grad_cam.py). If you follow the references on that site, you end up at the `compute_saliency()` function, which has a definition: "cls: class number to localize (-1 for most probable class)"